# collapsingtoolbarlayout. how to set it to be unexpanded and not scrollable programmatically

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in my app. I have a `recyclerview` of the news items that I pull from a service. Some have an associated image url and others don't. What I want to potentially do in my app is to have the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` be disabled (you can't collapse it) and collapsed (like a regular toolbar) if there is no associated image url pulled in from my service call. 
This doesn't seem to be trivial.

I've tried this in my activity.

```
 newsappbarlayout.setExpanded(false);
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)   newsappbarlayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 50;
    newsappbarlayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

but this code made my toolbar disappear completely!

I would also like to know if there is a way to set the collapse colour for the toolbar. I am currently using a pallette of the image but id like the image to fade to a specific colour when collapsed. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled)` to your recyclerview.